# Error saving object in ember.js: 'Object X has no method 'save''

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I'm building an application in Rails and Ember.js, and I'm having trouble creating new objects.  In my ember controller, when the save action is called, it attempts to call `this.get('model').save()`.  The actual object only requires one parameter, called 'content' to be created.  The error I'm getting is `Uncaught TypeError: Object xstringx has no method 'save'`, where `xstringx` is the actual value I typed into the content textarea box.

`this.get('model')` is actually returning a string!  How can I get it to return my model?  Here is some relevant code:

Routes:

```
App.MessagesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(){
    this.store.createRecord('message');
},
setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('content', model);
},
renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('app/templates/messages/new');
}
});
```

Controller:

```
App.MessagesNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
actions: {
    save: function(){
    return this.get('model').save().then(function(){
        return _this.transitionToRoute('messages.index');
    });
    }       
}

});
```

View:

```
App.MessagesNewView = Ember.View.extend({
templateName: "app/templates/messages/new",
actions: {
    save: function() {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
}
});
```

New Message Template:

```
<form role="form">
 <fieldset>
 <div class="form-group">
   <label {{bindAttr for="contentField.field_id"}}>Content</label>
  {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding='content' class='form-control' name='content' viewName='contentField'}}
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="submit" {{action "save"}} class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dancer">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Message Model:

```
App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
content: DS.attr('string'),
user_id: DS.attr('number'),
created_at: DS.attr('string'),
updated_at: DS.attr('string'),
user: DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true}),
priority: DS.attr('number'),
priorityClass: function(user_id){
     //Return the middle size until implemented
    return 'importance-medium';
}.property('priority')
});
```

Comment: Can you show your Message model?

Comment: When you use content, that property resolve to whole object instead of the `content` property of your model, update to `content.content`, or `model.content` like described by @michael-johnston and will work.

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior, binding to `content.content` and `model.content` are leading to undefined errors...

Comment: but do use `model.content`, `content` is deprecated.  ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I made the change!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if is a typo, but you need to return the data from your model method:

```
App.MessagesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.createRecord('message');
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model){
        controller.set('content', model);
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('app/templates/messages/new');
    }
});
```

And use `content.content` or `model.content` like described by Michael

```
{{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding='model.content' class='form-control' name='content' viewName='contentField'}}
```

Comment: Thanks!  The missing return statement combined with the model.content solved the problem.  Looks like I copied some coffeescript from an example and forgot to add the return.

Answer (score 1):

content is for legacy reasons a reserved word in Ember.

Try binding your textArea to `model.content`, or changing the attribute name to something else.

```
{{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding='model.content' class='form-control' name='content' viewName='contentField'}}
```

Comment: I'm now getting: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'save' of undefined`